# QtCreator Doxygen for c project

Tags: c, qt, doxygen

I have a pure C project and I want to document it using doxygen.
Doxygen plugin is succesfully installed for qtcreator and I have tested doxygen on a simple C++ project which was ok. But it doesn't work for C projects and the output of html files is empyt, just a index file and no other pages. It seems that it works only on C++ projects where classes are defined.
[Here](https://linux.m2osw.com/doxygen-does-not-generate-documentation-my-c-functions-or-any-global-function) it is said that for C files, it is mandatory to add a @file inside every header file. I also did this, but still it doesn't work. I don't know what but it seems that the configuration which doxygen plugin generates is configured to not work with C projects.

Comment: you have to use an appropriate `Doxyfile` that configures the doxygen tool.  I have such a file,,  However, with comments it is some 78+++ bytes long, so cannot be posted in an 'answer

Comment: @user3629249 One can reduce the size of the Doxyfile by means of the options -s -u (-s for no comment and -u for update, in this case to see that a new files is created.When posing only a reference to the doxygen version is required and the difference between the standard configuration file and the one used.

Comment: without the comments in the doxygen configuration file, it will be very difficult for the OP to be making any changes or even to understand what they are looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some little changes you can adapt this file:

```
/* doxygen.cfg */
```

---

```
PROJECT_NAME = "AppName"
PROJECT_NUMBER = "1.0"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = ../misc/doxygen
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE = Spanish
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C = YES
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS = YES
# If you want to generate code for .c files
SOURCE_BROWSER = YES
INLINE_SOURCES = YES
#
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
REFERENCES_RELATION = YES
INPUT =
FILE_PATTERNS = *.h *.c
RECURSIVE = YES
TAB_SIZE = 4
GENERATE_HTML = YES
GENERATE_LATEX = NO
```

Just run: `doxygen doxygen.cfg`